# convert django table to dict

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I have a django model like this(for example):

```
class Books(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

And I need to convert all data in this model to dict:

```
[{'author':1, 'books':[{'id':1, 'name':'Book1'}, {'id':2, 'name':'Book2'}]}, {'author':2, 'books':[{'id':3, 'name':'Book1'}, {'id':4, 'name':'Book2'}]}.....]
```

How I can do this?

I tried to use model_to_dict:

```
books = Books.objects.all()
data = model_to_dict(books, fields = ['author', 'id', 'name'])
```

But I have an error **`QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'`**

Same with `books = Books.objects.values()`

Comment: djangorestframework would make this very simple for you, essentially you need to write a serializer

Comment: Your example is not a dict, is a list. You want to group by author?

Comment: @Gocht yes, I need group by author.

Comment: @Sayse I know, but it's not optional in this project.

Comment: What is your Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
authors = Books.objects.distinct('author')
    authids = []
    for a in authors:
        authids.append(a.author.id)
    data = []
    for aid in authids:
        adict = {}
        books = Metro.objects.filter(author=aid)
        blist = []
        for b in books:
            book = {}
            book['id'] = b.id
            book['name'] = b.name
            blist.append(book)
        adict['aid'] = aid
        adict['books'] = blist
        data.append(adict)
    out = simplejson.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(out, content_type="application/json")
```

It looks not so optimized, but it definitely works.